ARIMAX-GARCH flattens when using daily return, but not level
Whenever I do my ARIMAX-GARCH model for forecasting n-ahead with sentiment from news as my exogenous variable, the predictions seems normal when forecasting using level price of the stock, but it heavily underestimates close to 0 when using daily return in percent change or log percent change.
As seen below the curve flattens out, and the results seems weird when I use daily change in %.

Here is my code. I change variable in my zoo when using daily return etc.

library(readxl)
library(vars)
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(rugarch)
library(forecast)

# Loading Data
finbert_OMX5 <- read_excel("~/desktop/omxc25procent.xlsx")

# Preparing Data
dates <- as.Date(finbert_OMX5$date)
FINsentiment3 <- zoo(finbert_OMX5$finbert_change, dates)
OMXdaily_return3 <- zoo(finbert_OMX5$Price, dates)

# Combined
fin_zoo4 <- merge(FINsentiment3, OMXdaily_return3)
fin_zoo4 <- fin_zoo4[order(index(fin_zoo4)),]

# Split data into train and test
split_index <- round(0.8 * nrow(fin_zoo4))
train_data <- fin_zoo4[1:split_index, ]
test_data <- fin_zoo4[(split_index + 1):nrow(fin_zoo4), ]

train_data_core <- coredata(train_data)
test_data_core <- coredata(test_data)

# Random Walk Model
random_walk_forecasts <- lag(test_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return3"], 1)
random_walk_forecasts[1] <- tail(train_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return3"], 1)  # First element from last of train set

# ARIMAX-GARCH Model Setup and Forecasting
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                   mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 2), include.mean = FALSE, external.regressors = matrix(train_data_core[, "FINsentiment3"], ncol = 1)),
                   distribution.model = "norm")
arimax_garch_forecasts <- numeric(nrow(test_data_core))

for(i in 1:nrow(test_data_core)) {
    current_train_data <- fin_zoo4[1:(split_index + i - 1), ]
    current_train_data_core <- coredata(current_train_data)
    
    if(i > 1) {
        xreg_train <- matrix(current_train_data_core[, "FINsentiment3"], ncol = 1)
        xreg_forecast <- matrix(test_data_core[i - 1, "FINsentiment3"], ncol = 1)
        
        spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
                           mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2, 2), include.mean = FALSE, external.regressors = xreg_train),
                           distribution.model = "norm")
        model <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = current_train_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return3"])
        forecast_info <- ugarchforecast(model, xreg = xreg_forecast, n.ahead = 1)
        forecast_mean <- forecast_info@forecast$seriesFor
        arimax_garch_forecasts[i] <- as.numeric(forecast_mean)
    }
}

# Calculate and Compare Metrics for Both Models
calculate_metrics <- function(forecasts, actuals) {
    errors <- forecasts - actuals
    # Exclude the first forecast
    errors <- errors[-1]
    actuals <- actuals[-1]
    list(
        RMSE = sqrt(mean(errors^2)),
        MAPE = mean(abs(errors) / abs(actuals)) * 100,
        SMAPE = mean(2 * abs(errors) / (abs(actuals) + abs(forecasts[-1]))) * 100,
        MedAE = median(abs(errors))
    )
}


arimax_garch_metrics <- calculate_metrics(arimax_garch_forecasts, test_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return3"])
random_walk_metrics <- calculate_metrics(random_walk_forecasts, test_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return3"])

# Print the metrics
cat("ARIMAX-GARCH Model Metrics:\n")
print(arimax_garch_metrics)
cat("\nRandom Walk Model Metrics:\n")
print(random_walk_metrics)

# Comparison table
actual_values <- test_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return3"]
comparison_df <- data.frame(Forecast = arimax_garch_forecasts, RandomWalk = random_walk_forecasts, Actual = actual_values)
print(comparison_df)

# Plotting forecasts and actual values without the first observation
plot_forecasts <- function(actuals, forecasts1, forecasts2, title) {
    plot(actuals[-1], type = "l", col = "blue", ylim = range(c(actuals[-1], forecasts1[-1], forecasts2[-1])),
         main = title, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Price/Returns")
    lines(forecasts1[-1], col = "red")
    lines(forecasts2[-1], col = "green")
    legend("topleft", legend = c("Actual", "ARIMAX-GARCH", "Random Walk"), 
           col = c("blue", "red", "green"), lty = 1)
}

# Plot the forecasts and actual values without the first observation
plot_forecasts(test_data_core[-1, "OMXdaily_return3"], arimax_garch_forecasts[-1], random_walk_forecasts[-1], "ARIMAX-GARCH vs Random Walk Forecast")
```


Your eyes may be tricking you. What matters is the vertical distance between the forecast and the corresponding realization. In the first graph, the vertical distance is quite hard to judge. Also, the scales of the vertical axes are different between the graphs. And the random walk forecast for the returns in the second graph is terrible compared to the ARIMAX-GARCH forecast (again, look at the vertical distance)! All in all, visual comparison between the two graphs is very difficulty and may easily be misleading.

I understand, the error metrics are better and such, but does it not seem as there could be some underlying issue when the model predicts near 0? And thus our exogenous variable has no explanatory effect to predict these movements. A flat line at 0 would also perform better than the random walk in this case

@BarneGeniet, there are two different things here. First, your post focuses on the comparison between the two pictures, and I have addressed that in my answer. Second, you are now interested in whether the exogenous variable not being a good predictor is a reason for concern. To answer the latter question, it depends on the context. Some predictors can be reasonably expected to have great predictive power, other not so much. You need subject-matter  (not statistical) knowledge to judge that.
